# How to avoid if else?

Tags: android, if-statement, checkbox, arraylist, android-sqlite

Im trying to do an application that, on the first activity, user can mark several checkbox, from 1 to seven or eight (it depends on final version). When user have marked his options and he click on a "search" button, I want to show a list showing diferent objects depending on the marked items.

My objects are custom objects "ground",it have many characteristics, like strings or int-boolean (1 or 0), stored in a database sqlite.
In my main activity, I use a lot of if else to know how many of checkbox are checked, I put this information into intent via extras, and in my second activity (list) I retrieve this extras and I do another if else to know what list the app must show. 
I think this method is such rudimentary because i have to do a lot of if else on both activities.
I have tried to make in the first activity a dbquery returning a list, and send this list via intent, but I have followed a lot of tutorials and always I have a list of correct number of objects but always the same overwrited object!

Any ideas of what to do?

Thank you in advance!

FIRST ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button bafegeix, bcerca, bneteja;
    ListView llista;
    RadioGroup grup;
    RadioButton casa, terreny;
    CheckBox cbaigua, cblavabos, cbcobert, cbdutxes, cbcuina, cbadap;
    protected Activity activity;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prova__db);


        bcerca = (Button) findViewById (R.id.cerca);
        bneteja = (Button) findViewById (R.id.neteja);
        grup = (RadioGroup)findViewById (R.id.grup);
        casa = (RadioButton)findViewById (R.id.casa);
        terreny = (RadioButton)findViewById (R.id.terreny);
        cbaigua = (CheckBox)findViewById (R.id.aigua);
        cblavabos = (CheckBox)findViewById (R.id.lavabos);
        cbcobert = (CheckBox)findViewById (R.id.cobert);
        cbdutxes = (CheckBox)findViewById (R.id.dutxes);
        cbcuina = (CheckBox)findViewById (R.id.cuina);
        cbadap = (CheckBox)findViewById (R.id.adaptada);



bcerca.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(terreny.isChecked()){


Intent iterreny = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LlistaTerrenys.class);
iterreny.putExtra("aigua", "aigua");    
iterreny.putExtra("lavabos", "lavabos");
iterreny.putExtra("cobert", "cobert");
iterreny.putExtra("dutxes", "dutxes");
startActivity(iterreny);


            }else if (cbaigua.isChecked()&& cblavabos.isChecked()&&cbcobert.isChecked()&&cbdutxes.isChecked()) {

                Intent iterreny = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LlistaTerrenys.class);
                iterreny.putExtra("aigua", "aigua");    
                iterreny.putExtra("lavabos", "lavabos");
                iterreny.putExtra("cobert","cobert");
                iterreny.putExtra("dutxes", "dutxes");
                startActivity(iterreny);

            } else if(cbaigua.isChecked()&&cblavabos.isChecked()&&cbcobert.isChecked()){

                Intent iterreny = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LlistaTerrenys.class);
                iterreny.putExtra("aigua", "aigua");    
                iterreny.putExtra("lavabos", "lavabos");
                iterreny.putExtra("cobert","cobert");
                startActivity(iterreny);

            }else if(cblavabos.isChecked()&&cbcobert.isChecked()&&cbdutxes.isChecked()){

                Intent iterreny2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LlistaTerrenys.class);
                iterreny.putExtra("lavabos", "lavabos");
                iterreny.putExtra("cobert", "cobert");
                iterreny.putExtra("dutxes", "dutxes");
                startActivity(iterreny);

            }else if(cbaigua.isChecked()&&cbcobert.isChecked()&&cbdutxes.isChecked()){

                Intent iterreny2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LlistaTerrenys.class);
                iterreny.putExtra("aigua", "aigua");
                iterreny.putExtra("cobert", "cobert");
                iterreny.putExtra("dutxes", "dutxes");
                startActivity(iterreny);

            }else if(cbaigua.isChecked()&&cblavabos.isChecked()&&cbdutxes.isChecked()){

                Intent iterreny2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LlistaTerrenys.class);
                iterreny.putExtra("aigua", "aigua");    
                iterreny.putExtra("lavabos", "lavabos");
                iterreny.putExtra("dutxes", "dutxes");
                startActivity(iterreny);

            }else if (cbaigua.isChecked()&&cblavabos.isChecked()){

                Intent iterreny2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LlistaTerrenys.class);
                iterreny.putExtra("aigua", "aigua");    
                iterreny.putExtra("lavabos", "lavabos");
                startActivity(iterreny);
```

SECOND ACTIVITY

public class LlistaTerrenys extends Activity {

```
ListView llista;
TextView numelements;
ArrayList<Terreny>list;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_list_contactos);


llista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
numelements = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numelements); 

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String aigua = extras.getString("aigua");
String lavabos = extras.getString("lavabos");
String cobert = extras.getString("cobert");
String dutxes = extras.getString("dutxes");
String seleccio = extras.getString("noseleccio");


if (aigua!=null && lavabos!=null && cobert!=null && dutxes!=null) {

    final UtilidadesSQL mydb = new UtilidadesSQL(getApplicationContext());
    mydb.getAllDataTerrenyTotesCaracteristiques();

    AdapterTerreny aa = new AdapterTerreny(this, mydb.getAllDataTerrenyTotesCaracteristiques());
    llista.setAdapter(aa);



} else if(aigua!=null && lavabos!=null && cobert!=null){

    final UtilidadesSQL mydb = new UtilidadesSQL(getApplicationContext()); 
    AdapterTerreny aa = new AdapterTerreny(this, mydb.getAllDataTerrenyAiguaLavabosCobert());
    llista.setAdapter(aa);





}else if(lavabos!=null && cobert!=null && dutxes!=null){

    final UtilidadesSQL mydb = new UtilidadesSQL(getApplicationContext()); 
    AdapterTerreny aa = new AdapterTerreny(this, mydb.getAllDataTerrenyLavabosCobertDutxes());
    llista.setAdapter(aa);




}else if(aigua!=null && cobert!=null && dutxes!=null){

    final UtilidadesSQL mydb = new UtilidadesSQL(getApplicationContext()); 
    AdapterTerreny aa = new AdapterTerreny(this, mydb.getAllDataTerrenyAiguaCobertDutxes());
    llista.setAdapter(aa);





}else if(aigua!=null && lavabos!=null && dutxes!=null){

    final UtilidadesSQL mydb = new UtilidadesSQL(getApplicationContext()); 
    AdapterTerreny aa = new AdapterTerreny(this, mydb.getAllDataTerrenyAiguaLavabosDutxes());
    llista.setAdapter(aa);




}else if (aigua!=null &&  lavabos!=null ){

    final UtilidadesSQL mydb = new UtilidadesSQL(getApplicationContext()); 
    AdapterTerreny aa = new AdapterTerreny(this, mydb.getAllDataTerrenyAiguaLavabos());
    llista.setAdapter(aa);
```

HERE DIFFERENT METHODS RETRIEVING DATA FROM SQL

```
         public Cursor getAllDataTerrenyAigua () {
             SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
              String buildSQL = ("select * from terrenys where aigua = ?");

                return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, new String[]{"1"});
            }



         public Cursor getAllDataTerrenyLavabos () {
             SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
              String buildSQL = ("select * from terrenys where lavabos = ?");

                return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, new String[]{"1"});
            }



         public Cursor getAllDataTerrenyCobert () {
             SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
              String buildSQL = ("select * from terrenys where cobert = ?");

                return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, new String[]{"1"});
            }



         public Cursor getAllDataTerrenyDutxes () {
             SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
              String buildSQL = ("select * from terrenys where dutxes = ?");

                return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, new String[]{"1"});
            }



         public Cursor getAllDataTerrenyTotesCaracteristiques () {
             SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
              String buildSQL = ("select * from terrenys where aigua=? AND cobert=? AND dutxes=? AND lavabos=?");

              return db.rawQuery(buildSQL, new String[]{"1","1","1","1"});
            }
```

Comment: I'd rather use a switch statement, and setting the values of the objects after the switch statement.

Comment: Hi Tobias! if I use switch and case I'm not in the same scenario? make so many s&c statments as checkbox possible combinations?

Comment: Thank you Tobias! I don't know if my final solution is what you was saying, but with your comment I get the solution!